# ubuntu does not see usb-connected printer (Brother DCP-J100)

Tags: usb, printing

I'm running Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 6.2.0-35-generic GNU/Linux

I try to install Brother DCP-J100 printer. I have already installed drivers (from Brother), but the printer and the scanner do not work. It appears to be no fault in Cups. The printer is not being detected:
`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1c4f:0026 SiGma Micro Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1c4f:0003 SiGma Micro HID controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have already tried obvious solutions: usb disabled on the mainboard, wrong cables, a faulty usb-port (have tried several), no power :) etc. This printer worked perfectly on the other Linux computer.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I desperately tried different combinations of USB sockets (both in the computer and printer) and finally used USB 3 (blue) socket. Nothing happened and then, after half an hour, "Brother" uppeared in the list of devices (lsusb) and on the list of printers in cups.

I don't know if this is the solution or just a "solution" (maybe using usb 3 for connecting printers is obvious for everyone except me). Hope someone with better manners decide.